# Working with Github repositories (merge, reset) without cloning

Tags: git, github

Imagine that I've forked a Github repository, and after making many changes, discover that it's impossible to automatically merge my pull request.

But I don't want to clone the mother repository to my local drive in order to `reset --hard` or `merge -f`.

My main problem here are remotes - I can't seem to find a way to add remote references to something like Github API, and thus I can't merge my **remote repository** into the parent repository that I originally forked from.

Tell me if I'm not being clear, I'd gladly edit my question.

Comment: You're pretty much hosed. Take this as a lesson to always keep all of your repo's updated. Or even better is to refine them into one repo. Good luck!

Comment: It's not that bad, I can always clone both repos to different files and work down on my disk, but I was hoping for a better option.

Comment: No matter what you do, you're going to end up manually merging some files. And depending on how far off the two repos are from each other, you have a ton of merging to do...

Comment: I've actually never manually merged files... I tend to favor overwriting.

Comment: Yikes... If you've ever collaborated on a project with other programmers, I can guarantee you that you've pissed them off a couple times by overwriting their work.

Comment: Haha, I'm much more careful when collaborating with other public projects. I only overwrite (and do long runs without merges) in my own repos. My collaborating ethics aren't *that* bad.

Comment: Why are you conflicting with yourself--and thus overwriting?  Smells like a bad workflow to me.

Comment: @jszakmeister True, I'm still quite new to Git, and trying to get used to the workflow process. Any links/references that outline what a good git workflow looks like?

Comment: It really depends on the project, how many people are involved, etc.  Many folks like Vincent Driessen's [model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and wrote a tool called [`git flow`](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) to help people follow it.  Atlassian has put up a [reference](http://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows) that's helpful too.  And there are some real [simple guides](http://nakedstartup.com/2010/04/simple-daily-git-workflow) to get you through the day.

Comment: Thanks, @jszakmeister - looking through those right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here.  First, you don't merge repositories, you merge branches.  Repositories just hold the branches and the commits associated with them.  Secondly, in order to add a remote to your local repository, you don't need to interact with the GitHub API.  And I'd advise against adding a remote to your remote repository, because it will not automatically stay up-to-date.

What I typically do is add a new `upstream` remote to my local repository:

```
git remote add upstream <url-to-parent>
```

Fetch the updated references:

```
git fetch upstream
```

Now you have access to the most recent data from the parent repository.  The nice part is that most of the objects in the repository will be reused, so you're not going to have an entirely separate copy.  Now you can access what's in the parent repo via the `upstream` remote.  For example, you can merge in the most recent version of master in the parent repository:

```
git merge upstream/master
```

You can also rebase your current set of changes on the updated master (*be careful with this!*):

```
git rebase upstream/master
```

I tend to prefer the latter when it's a private branch.  Sometimes the former is necessary if someone is building on top of my branch.  If you've not dealt with rebase, you probably don't want this to be your first experience with it.  You'll want to experiment in a less stressful, and more controlled environment.

Whatever you decide to do, definitely learn to deal with merge conflicts.  Most are pretty easy to sort out, and in the long run it will make life with Git (or any other VCS) better.

**Update**

After some discussion in the comments, it's now clear that you want to merge your work back into the upstream.  Yes, this is entirely possible.  In fact, if you've merged `upstream/master` into your master branch, all you really need to do is:

```
git push upstream master
```

That will push your master branch to the master branch project's remote repository.  Its should be a fast-foward, and no reason to use `--force`.  If you do see some advice about not being able to fast-forward, or to use `--force`, be careful.  There's a strong likelihood of losing data.

In this mode, I greatly prefer to use `git rebase upstream/master` followed by a `git push upstream master` to avoid seeing things like `"Merging upstream/master into master"` in the log messages.  As I mentioned before, `git rebase` does have it's own set of concerns too.

In this mode, master is where all the merging and resolution happens between you and the upstream.  You cannot directly merge into a remote ref because there is no branch associated with it (locally).  `git merge` needs a working tree to work from just in case there are merge conflicts.  But you really don't need it in your scenario.  Once you merge the upstream master branch, you can then push your branch up without issue.

Comment: Okay, so obviously my question was not stated properly. The branch that I want to merge into is the one that's not cloned, while the base branch *is* cloned. So basically what I want to do is `git merge master/upstream`. Thanks for the great answer though, an upvote for you.

Comment: I'm still sure I understand you.  I think you're saying you have a local branch in your repo, that was created from a branch that also exists on the remote (perhaps `master`?).  The above flow works whether or not your branch exists on the remote.  It sounds like you've got something other aspect that you're looking for an answer on... can you elaborate on that a little more?

Comment: I'm not working with two branches from the same repo. I'm working with two separate branches on two separate repos (you know, like when you fork a repo). The repo that I forked from is in the cloud, while my fork is on the disk. I'm merging `master` from the forked repo *into* `master` from the original (in the cloud) repo.

Comment: Are you committing to your master?  What I typically do is work on topic branches which get pushed up to my repo (origin), but they all start from master, which tracks the upstream (separate) repo.  I've been using [a script that I wrote](https://github.com/jszakmeister/etc/blob/master/git-addons/git-ffwd) to help fast-forward my local branches.  It helps me keep master up-to-date, even though I don't work on it much (or at all, depending on my commit privileges).  Once I push up the topic branch to my repo, I get it back into the upstream through a pull request (for GitHub).

Comment: It doesn't really matter which branch I'm committing to (yes, it is `master`), because **I need to merge changes from my local branch into a remote branch from a separate repository that is not cloned**.

Comment: I'm not trying to argue with you.  It's just an easier workflow to have `master` follow the upstream, while you put your changes on a different branch that go somewhere else.  But it looks to me my answer hits the spot: add the remote, `git merge upstream/master` and call it a day.  BTW, I think you stated that backwards: it appears your interesting in merging the upstream remote branch into your local repository.

Comment: I'm not arguing either (sorry if I sound like I am) - I still don't think my problem is understood. I don't think it's stated backwards: I am interested in merging *from* my local branch *into* the remote. Is this possible? (Doesn't `git merge upstream/master` merge *from* the remote *into* the local?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28471/discussion-between-jszakmeister-and-albert-xing)

Comment: @AlbertXing No worries.  You're description initially said the opposite.  I didn't realize you need the other way too.  I updated my answer.

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for hanging with me to get it figured out!